# Regex for finding a line in a section

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a line in haproxy configuration file:

```
global
        log 127.0.0.1   local0
        log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
        #log loghost    local0 info
        maxconn 32768
        tune.maxaccept -1
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        daemon
        stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 600 level admin
        stats timeout 2m
        timeout http-request 5000

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        retries 5
        option redispatch
        maxconn 16384
        timeout connect 7s
        timeout client  500s
        timeout server  500s
        timeout http-request 7000
        timeout client-fin      30s
        timeout tunnel  1h
```

What is the regex to match the line `timeout http-request 5000` but only in `global` section. Also, we need to ensure to exclude `#`.

Comment: What programming language are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the pattern

```
^global\b(?:(?:(?:#|[ \t]+)[^\n]*|)\n)*?\s+(timeout\s+http-request\s+\d+)
```

with multiline modifier `m`. This should support commented lines (with `#`) and doesn't rely on the `defaults` section being after the `globals` section like all the other answers seem to do.

The text `timeout http-request 5000` will be in capture group 1.

[Regex101 demo.](https://regex101.com/r/wY6eR6/3)

Explanation:

```
^global\b      find the "global" section, this must not be indented
(?:            then consume any number of lines that are...
   (?:
      (?:#     ...commented...
      |[ \t]+) ...or indented...
      [^\n]*   
      |        ...or empty
    )\n
)*?
\s+(timeout\s+http-request\s+\d+)   finally capture the line we're looking for
```

Comment: This works. I am not sure why others have marked this question as a "need to learn regex" question. I know regex pretty well but yeah not a pro to write such complex regex. Anyways, thanks a lot Rawing for helping me out, I will try using regex101 from now on. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi @Rawing, Stuck again.    `case "$1" in
    start)
        echo -n "Starting haproxy "
        ## Start daemon with startproc(8). If this fails
        ## the return value is set appropriately by startproc.
        haproxy_check
        /sbin/startproc $HAPROXY_BIN -D -f $HAPROXY_CONF -p $HAPROXY_PID
        # Remember status and be verbose
        rc_status -v
        ;;
` - in this i want to match haproxy_check. I tried various things including `^\s*start\)(?:(?:(?:#|[ \t]+)[^\n]*|)\n)*?^\s*haproxy_check`. This seems to timeout if haproxy_check is commented out. Any help?

Comment: @praving5 You need to give some more details about what you're trying to do. If all you say is "I want to match haproxy_check", then, well, the regex `haproxy_check` should do. Probably best to post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this regex: https://regex101.com/r/sI5qY6/1

```
/global.*(timeout\s+http-request\s+\d+).*?defaults/s
```

It gives following match:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [304-329]   `timeout http-request 5000`
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will probably do it very fast only in 66 steps in case timeout http-request 5000 is at the very end of global

```
timeout\shttp-request\s+\d+(?=\s*defaults)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/q1PA6EG6L9sD8lYL)

https://regex101.com/r/yW9xZ6/2

if timeout http-request 5000 can be placed anywhere in global group then

```
/timeout\shttp-request\s+\d+(?=[\s\S]+defaults)/m
```

https://regex101.com/r/yW9xZ6/3

Answer (score 0):

`awk` is handy to search winthin a block.

Give this a try:

```
awk -F "#" '/^global/,/^defaults/ {if ($1 ~ /timeout *http-request/) {print $1}}' haproxy.conf
```

`-F "#"` define `#` as field separator, so `$1` is the string before `#` in current line.

`'/^global/,/^defaults/ {` for all lines within the block defined between `global` and `defaults`, do the actions between `{}`.

`if ($1 ~ /timeout *http-request/` it is true if the string before `#` (if any), contains the property `timeout *http-request`.